# what methods does `foo < bar < baz` actually invoke?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

In python we can say:

```
if foo < bar < baz:
    do something.
```

and similarly, we can overload the comparision operators like:

```
class Bar:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        do something else
```

but what methods of the types of the operands of those interval comparisions are actually called? is the above equivalent to

```
if foo.__lt__(bar) and bar.__lt__(baz):
    do something.
```

Edit: re S.Lott, Here's some output that helps to illustrate what actually happens.

```
>>> class Bar:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print('__init__', self.name)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        print('__lt__', self.name, other.name)
        return self.name < other.name

>>> Bar('a') < Bar('b') < Bar('c')
('__init__', 'a')
('__init__', 'b')
('__lt__', 'a', 'b')
('__init__', 'c')
('__lt__', 'b', 'c')
True
>>> Bar('b') < Bar('a') < Bar('c')
('__init__', 'b')
('__init__', 'a')
('__lt__', 'b', 'a')
False
>>>
```

Comment: +1: You could (and did) answer your own question.  -1: You certainly didn't need to ask this here, since finding the answer was clearly easier and quicker than asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __lt__(self, other):
        print('__lt__', self.name, other.name)
        return True

a,b,c = Bar('a'), Bar('b'), Bar('c')

a < b < c
```

Output:

```
('__lt__', 'a', 'b')
('__lt__', 'b', 'c')
True
```

Comment: to a certain extent, i'm also very interested in wether `and` is being used, or some other clever thing is also going on.

Comment: With some testing, it looks like it must do something essentially similar.  I can arrange for the second comparison to be short circuited by having the first be false.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: As you can see in my second example, it's a little bit more than a simple and, since bar could be a mutating function.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it gave me enough code to use in the interactive interpreter to give me all the info I actually needed, though both answers were very informative.

Answer (score 13):

```
if foo < bar < baz:
```

is equivalent to

```
if foo < bar and bar < baz:
```

with one important distinction: if bar is a mutating, it will be cached. I.e.:

```
if foo < bar() < baz:
```

is equivalent to

```
tmp = bar()
if foo < tmp and tmp < baz:
```

But to answer your question, it will end up being:

```
if foo.__lt__(bar) and bar.__lt__(baz):
```

Comment: Wow, first three lines of my post was going to be the same as yours, excepting a single colon. +1 to you. ;)

Answer (score 3):

It uses successive calls to the less-than comparison operator:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo(a,b,c):
...     return a < b < c
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 DUP_TOP             
              7 ROT_THREE           
              8 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             11 JUMP_IF_FALSE            8 (to 22)
             14 POP_TOP             
             15 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
             18 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             21 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   22 ROT_TWO             
             23 POP_TOP             
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: +1 for generated code.  This merely reinforces that the cutsy syntax I had planned for a class won't happen safely.  But I learned so much it was worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

It calls the special method `__lt__()`, and if needed it will call `__nonzero__()` to coerce the result of `__lt__()` to a boolean. Surprisingly (to me at least), there is no `__and__()` method to override the `and` operator.

Here's a test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        print "%s.__lt__(%s)" % (self, other)
        return Bar("%s.__lt__(%s)" % (self, other))

    def __nonzero__(self):
        print "%s.__nonzero__()" % (self)
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

foo = Bar("foo")
bar = Bar("bar")
baz = Bar("baz")

if foo < bar < baz:
    pass
```

Output:

```
foo.__lt__(bar)
foo.__lt__(bar).__nonzero__()
bar.__lt__(baz)
bar.__lt__(baz).__nonzero__()
```

Comment: `and` isn't an operator in this context, it's a mechanism to describe control flow (obviously in another context there's a bitwise `and`, for which there is a proper operator and an `__and__` override).  Keep in mind that `and` doesn't actually compare anything, it just evaluates each member of the expression for truth, and when it finds one that's false it bails out.  Asking for a method to override `and` is like asking for a method to override `if`.